# Convert a column of a text file to scientific notation

Tags: python, numpy, text, scientific-notation

I have a text file with one column and many raws (BBB.txt). I want to convert all the numbers to scientific notation. I am trying like below:

```
z= loadtxt ('BBB.txt')
for i in z:
    with open ('ff.txt','w') as h:
        y=np.format_float_scientific(z)
        h.write("\n".join(map(lambda z: '%f' % z, y)))
```

I will have an error "only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars". What is the problem here?

The text file is like below, but with more raws:

```
0.000000
0.261869
0.980796
2.119419
3.218744
3.875440
-38.159080
-54.630055
-69.909509
```

Comment: What does `x` refer to here?

Comment: It is mistake. it should be "z"

Comment: The error "only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars" is returned when the function expects a single value but you pass an array instead. So please could you add more information about your text file content?

Comment: I added a sample in the question.

Comment: try `y=np.format_float_scientific(z[0])`, my guess is that z here is still an array which brings up the error. EDIT: this is wrong. `z` is the whole file

Comment: Oh. it should be `y=np.format_float_scientific(i)`. notice the `i` instead of `z`

Comment: It is not working true. then the all number will convert to "0.e+00"

Comment: The more I look at it, the weirder it gets. You overwrite the ff.txt file every new row in z. Is that what you want?

Comment: `y=np.format_float_scientific(i)` this is not converting all numbers to `"0.e+00"`. Have you tried?

Comment: Yes, i've just checked it myself too. There is another error in the last instruction

Answer (score 0):

I'll leave it up to you what you want to do with the scientific notation. This converts the column to scientific notations.

```
import numpy as np

z= np.loadtxt ('BBB.txt')
with open("ff.txt", 'w') as file:
    for i in z:
        y=np.format_float_scientific(i)
        file.write("{}\n".format(y))
```

You tried to convert the whole file `z`. And python told you it wasn't possible. `z` is an array with a size bigger than 1

Comment: he wants to write out as a file. You have missing part in your code.

Comment: Added. Wasn't part of the question.

Answer (score 0):

You have confused about your namings in x,y,z,i. I always recommend to you to use long names for variables. Below script will help you

```py
import numpy as np
z = open('BBB.txt')
for i in z:
    with open ('ff.txt','a') as h:
        i=float(i)
        y=np.format_float_scientific(i)
        h.write(f"{y}\n")
```

With your style of your code you should use append `a` to write in file rather than `w`.

Comment: @Nerd its important to people understand that your problem is answered. Accept this post as answered and upvote.